# MongoDB Query to array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am having a collection orders , inside collection I am having attributes Array , I want to group the records on **attributes.value** where **attributes.name is "sugery"**

```
db.orders.find({},{"attributes":1}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(3);
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("599cfdb0f6ec8d00015b0880"), 
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a220ad86210001997d5a"), 
            "name" : "patient", 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "value" : "Lincon Burrows"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a229ad86210001997d5c"), 
            "name" : "notes", 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "value" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a230ad86210001997d5e"), 
            "name" : "surgeon", 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "value" : "Dr. Williams"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a238ad86210001997d60"), 
            "name" : "surgery", 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "value" : "Heart Surgery"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("599c357a9ec26c00017892a6"), 
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "value" : "new patient", 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "name" : "patient", 
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a220ad86210001997d5a")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "", 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "name" : "notes", 
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a229ad86210001997d5c")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "http://localhost:4200/#new surgeon", 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "name" : "surgeon", 
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a230ad86210001997d5e")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "new surgery", 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "name" : "surgery", 
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a238ad86210001997d60")
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("599c2069b2afd900019ea142"), 
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "value" : "Mellisa Darwin", 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "name" : "patient", 
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a220ad86210001997d5a")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "", 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "name" : "notes", 
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a229ad86210001997d5c")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "Dr. Josefina P. Robles", 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "name" : "surgeon", 
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a230ad86210001997d5e")
        }, 
        {
            "value" : "Spine Surgery", 
            "sysDefined" : NumberInt(1), 
            "status" : NumberInt(1), 
            "name" : "surgery", 
            "id" : ObjectId("5979a238ad86210001997d60")
        }
    ]
}
```

I want output like

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":"Heart Surgery",
      "count":1
   },
   {  
      "_id":"new surgery",
      "count":1
   },
   {  
      "_id":"Spine Surgery",
      "count":1
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

please see mongodb documentation for group. [db.collection.group()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/#examples)

The following are examples of the [db.collection.group()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.group/#examples) method. The examples assume an orders collection with documents of the following prototype:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5085a95c8fada716c89d0021"),
  ord_dt: ISODate("2012-07-01T04:00:00Z"),
  ship_dt: ISODate("2012-07-02T04:00:00Z"),
  item: {
       sku: "abc123",
       price: 1.99,
       uom: "pcs",
       qty: 25
  }
}
```

**Group by Two Fields**

The following example groups by the **ord_dt** and **item.sku** fields those documents that have **ord_dt** greater than **01/01/2012**:

```
db.runCommand({
 group:
   {
     ns: 'orders',
     key: { ord_dt: 1, 'item.sku': 1 },
     cond: { ord_dt: { $gt: new Date( '01/01/2012' ) } },
     $reduce: function ( curr, result ) { },
     initial: { }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
orders.aggregate({"attributes":1}, {$unwind:"$attributes"},{$match:{"attributes.name":"surgery"}})
```